# Python beautifulsoup and openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, beautifulsoup, openpyxl

So, i'm trying to use beautifulsoup for data extraction (a web crawler/scrapper), and i'm trying to iterate over each tag in the html to find the data that i want. My objective is to get an specific information and throw that into an excel sheet with the openpyxl library. Here's as example:

```
<table id="Table">   
    <tr>
        <th>Info A1</th>
        <th>Info B1</th>
        <th>Info C1</th>
        <th>Info D1</th>
        <th>Info E1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Info A2</th>
        <th>Info B2</th>
        <th>Info C2</th>
        <th>Info D2</th>
        <th>Info E2</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Basically, what i want to do is compare all the "A number" infos on the table, and if one of them matches to the info that i have, i'll get the rest of the infos that are in the same tr, and put it into an excel file. The true table is waaaaay bigger than this one from the example, and i already had success iterating it, but i don't know how to indentify the information that i want and compare it with the info that i already have.

Comment: You should show us your code.  As you iterate through the rows, you'll gather each cell into a list until you decide if this is a row you want.  Once you decide that, you can pump the list into your Excel table.

Answer (score 1):

```
d={}
for tr in soup.findAll('tr'):
    key = tr.text.split()[0]
    val = tr.text.split()[1:]
    d[key] = val
for key in d:
    if key in my_list:
        print(key) #prints the match from your list
        print(d[key]) #prints the values attached to the match
```

Creates an empty dictionary, iterates through the soup (where your table should reside) adding every A value as a key and every B/C/D/E as the key value in a list.

Then, for every key (A value) in the dictionary, check if they appear in my_list (your list of A values); if a match is found execute the print statements (which should be changed according to your needs) with key corresponding to the A value and d[key] corresponding to B/C/D/E values for the given A value.